# In-App Update not restarting app UI on Android 10 and above, it works fine below android version 10, how can I resolve this issue?

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-update

Flexible update working fine but immediate update downloading and installing the new apk but not restarting itself

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: have you tried this solution in manifest, android:launchMode="singleTask" to the launcher activity.